# jQuery not working in Firefox because of event.returnValue deprecation

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser, cross-browser

I know there are already a lot of topics about this subject, but I didn't find anything helpful yet.
I have a jQuery code to show and hide a div.

In chrome this is working fine, in Firefox it isn't

I checked my console in chrome which says 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.'

But I don't have event.returnValue.
Also the suggestion isn't working (event.preventDefault)

This is my js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aanmelden_event").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".event_subscribe").toggleClass("uitgeklapt");
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my css:

```
.event_subscribe{
    height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
}
```

And with the extra class:

```
.event_subscribe.uitgeklapt{
    height: 800px;
    
}
```

I think it is something in my jQuery, something with event.preventDefault.
I already tried e.preventdefault and some other suggested solutions by other topics.
Which didn't work unfortunately.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong here?
I use jquery-1.10.2.min.js btw.

Comment: You haven't set `event`. That might cause a problem

Comment: You can ignore the *"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."* message, it's not related to your problem (and is fixed in jQuery 1.11).

Comment: Change to `function(event)` on the click function

Comment: IE has a global event object, adopted by Chrome as well, but not present in Firefox, so you have to add the event argument in the function

Comment: you need to add event like this $(".aanmelden_event").click(function(event){

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't accepted the `event` argument in your function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aanmelden_event").click(function(event){
    // Here -----------------------------^
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".event_subscribe").toggleClass("uitgeklapt");
    });
});
</script>
```

Consequently, `event` is undefined and that code throws before it can toggle the class. You should have had an error in the console listing a `ReferenceError` because you tried to read the value of an undeclared variable.

The reason it works in some other browsers is that there's a global `event` object (originally in IE, and then it was supplied by Chrome and some others to be compatible with scripts written for IE). Firefox doesn't do that, there is no global `event`.

Comment: When not defined via 'var' or function parameter, event defaults to window.event.

Comment: @Bora: Not in Firefox, and not in any specification. IE does that, and Chrome (now) does as well to be compatible with code originally written for IE.

Comment: Thank you, the solution was indeed to call (event) after function.
But t did not give me the error you thought

Comment: IE and Chrome support the global window.event.FF does not. And, yes, it's true that this is not the standard, with which FF complies.